# Confusion in SQLite for ado.net

Tags: .net, sqlite

I just started off with SQLite. I wanted to do connectivity via ADO. I searched for drivers and found 2 of them :-

1. [http://system.data.sqlite.org/](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki)
2. [http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/)

I'm confused about which one to use. I tried installing both and, both of them are in the same namespace. Are they both same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is actually a fork from the second one. I say fork, but really the first one is *the* direct descendant of the second one:

> This is a fork of the popular ADO.NET adapter for SQLite known as
>   System.Data.SQLite. The originator of System.Data.SQLite, Robert
>   Simpson, is aware of this fork, has expressed his approval, and has
>   commit privileges on the new Fossil repository. The SQLite development
>   team intends to maintain System.Data.SQLite moving forward.
>
> Historical versions, as well as the original support forums, may still
>   be found at http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/, though there have been no
>   updates to this version since April of 2010.

Ref.: http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki

The bottom line is: use the first one. It almost always includes the latest version of sqlite, and also, the maintenance is tightly coupled with the maintenance of sqlite itself.